# Sqlite weird rawQuery behavior in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I use rawQuery method of a SQLiteDatabase object.

When I write

db.rawQuery("select * from xxx order by ? desc;", new String[] {"edit_time"});

it won't order the result.

But when I write

db.rawQuery("select * from xxx order by edit_time desc;", null);

it orders.

I did something wrong?

---

Thanks to sandis, I found I misread the document. There shouldn't be the ";". But removing the ";" doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: When you put stuff in the selection args they are bound as strings, they're not made part of the SQL automagically. If you want to make the ordering variable concat the string with the column to sort on.

Comment: @Jens I can't pick a comment as correct answer, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jens said the first query:

```
db.rawQuery("select * from xxx order by ? desc;", new String[] {"edit_time"});
```

Becomes:

```
select * from xxx order by 'edit_time' desc
```

Since we are not concerned with SQL injections on column names, you should use:

```
db.rawQuery("select * from xxx order by edit_time desc", null);
```

The selectionArgs are intended to be used in this manner:

```
db.rawQuery("select * from xxx order by edit_time like ? desc", new String[] { "%" + orderBy + "%"});
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) specifies `"The SQL string must not be ; terminated"`, perhaps that is the source of your problem.

Comment: Just tested. With or without ;, the second one works, the first one doesn't.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first one doesn't work if you remove the semi-colon after desc?  If that's the case that blows the theory in my answer to hell.